# MongoDB Shard Key vs Query Index

Tags: mongodb

I have set up my first mongodb sharded cluster and am finally at the stage where I create a db/collection and choose the shard key. I’ve read about how to choose an appropriate shard key and am likely going with a hashed index but I might be having some conceptual misunderstandings.

My documents are super simple and contain a document id (some natural number), a document version id (a natural number), and a string of the raw text itself. If I understand correctly from the documentation, I can choose to shard on the document id but this can lead to jumbo shards since the document id will be incremented and new documents will be added to the same shard. And so I could set the shard key as a hashed value of the document id.

My question is whether or not I can still continue to query by the document id? My brain is making me doubt this and making me think that the indexing of the documents is over the hashed shard key and not over the document id. I am hoping that the hashed shard key is used strictly for sharding and that I can set any key (i.e., document id) to be indexed. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can still query by the value of the shard key.

If you are referring to _id, that will be automatically indexed with it's natural value, otherwise you could explicitly create and index on the document id that is not hashed in addition to the shard key index.

As long as you test for equality to a single or explicit list of values, the query should be handled by the minimum number of shards.

However, if you use a ranged test such as $gte,  the query will have to be forwarded to every shard to be processed.

Using the hashed document id as the shard key will result in the creation of an index for the hashed value in addition to any other indexes.

There is a pretty good description of hashed sharding [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/hashed-sharding/index.html#hashed-sharding)

Comment: So I don't really care about the shard key when it comes to querying. I'm only using the shard key to ensure that the documents are evenly distributed. I currently have an empty collection that is sharded with `"_id": "hashed"` and then I plan to add documents with keys `document_id`, `date`, `text` and then create an index on `document_id` using `db.collection_name.create_index([('document_id', pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)`

Comment: Using _id as the shard key but document_id as your primary query field will mean that the mongos router with forward every query to every shard since there will be no way to determine which shard might hold the data.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but how would i know what the hashed shard key is for given document_id? Is there a way to get the hashed value from a document_id (i.e., is the hashing function available?)? I thought that the hashed shard key was generated randomly and had no association from the document_id (the document_id is unique and monotonically increasing so it cannot be used as a shard key since it will result in jumbo shards). Is there a way to tell mongo to generate a hashed shard key based on the document_id as I insert documents into an initially empty collection?

Comment: You don't have to know the hash.  You query for the raw value, and if that field is used in a hashed index, the mongod will calculate the hash as necessary.  The point I was making is you should select the shard key for a collection to be field that most of your queries will filter on, so you can minimize how many shards are involved in processing the query.